# Is it possible to create and then add to a nested collection in a firestore transaction?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Im hitting a permission error when I run this:

```
xDocRef = fs.collection("x").doc()
yDocRef = fs.collection("y").doc()
zDocRef = fs.collection("y").doc(yDocRef.id).collection("z").doc()
tx {
  await tx.set(xDocRef, xRecord);
  await tx.set(yDocRef, yRecord);
  await tx.set(zDocRef, zRecord);
}
```

But not when I change it to this:

```
xDocRef = fs.collection("x").doc()
yDocRef = fs.collection("y").doc()
zDocRef = fs.collection("y").doc(yDocRef.id).collection("z").doc()
tx {
  await tx.set(xDocRef, xRecord);
  await tx.set(yDocRef, yRecord);
}
zDocRef.set(zRecord)
```

Am I not allowed to create subcollections for new records in transactions?

Comment: Your client code is allowed to do whatever your security rules permit.  Without seeing your rules, it's not possible to say what's wrong.  Please edit the question to show your rules, and explain why you think the code should work given those rules. Also please show the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: Also worth noting that there is no operation to create a subcollection.  Collections simply appear in the console when a document has been written to it, and it will disappear after the last document is deleted from it.  They are not like filesystem directories that need to be created before files can be added to them.

Comment: I hear what you're saying and will post rules in a bit. But consider the example - the only difference is that the final set happens outside of the transaction. No rule spec should cause this behavior, I think.

Comment: Hey there, could you please tell me what is the error you are getting?